# iOS 6 iad not showing in simulator

Tags: ios, iad, simulator, ios6

After I update XCode to get iOS 6 SDK, I see that iAd is not loaded anymore on simulator. I can't try on real device for the moment as I've not updated my iPhone yet.

I didn't find anything about it on the release notes.

Anyone encountring the same issue and resolved it ?

Comment: The question as it stands is not a good fit for SO. You most likely do not want to know if anyone else got that issue but you want to know how to solve it, correct? If so, make sure you edit your question accordingly.

Comment: A game developer associate reports that iads is broken in iOS6 for all his games. No fix yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a post from a moderator of developer apple forum :

> Initial fill rates will reflect the recent launch of iOS 6. Thank you for your patience as we continue to ramp up ad serving.

It seem that ads will appears soon.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem with the ads that I have on apps in the app store and newly created apps.  After going through the iOS dev forums, and like a few have stated on here, basically its a server issue with apple.  There is nothing we can do but wait it out.  This is even causing errors in newly created projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is the error is always returned with iOS 6.  Both in simulator and on device.  When using the iOS simulator with iOS 5.0 a test ad appears as expected.  I no longer have an iOS 5.0 device to verify that the behavior is the same with it.